# Expanding disks lead to what packing of the plane?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, discrete-geometry, circle-packing

Suppose one sprinkles points uniformly at random on the infinite Euclidean plane,
with some density $\rho$ per unit area.
View the points as disks of radius zero.
Now the radii $r$ of all disks grows simultaneously at the same (slow) rate,
with the disks pushing one another when they come into contact,
with never two disk interiors overlapping.
Each disk-disk contact pushes both disks apart along the line connecting
their centers.
More complex clusters move the disks by summing the disk-disk force-separation
vectors, although I want the disks to move only when pushed, i.e.,
they never gain momentum to drift without pushing.
Three time-snapshots for a region containing $8$ points
might look like this (just a hand simulation):

          
[image: ExpandingDisks]

Here the disks do not yet touch at $t=1$ (blue), but at $t=2$ (tan),
$\lbrace 1,2 \rbrace$ and
$\lbrace 7,8 \rbrace$ are in contact, and by $t=3$ (pink),
$\lbrace 1,2,3,4 \rbrace$ and
$\lbrace 5,6,7,8 \rbrace$ are touching.

Although the model is not fully specified, perhaps analogous processes
have been studied in the literature?
Essentially I want to know:

> **Q**. What happens?
>   Is there some limit configuration as $r$ grows?

Intuitively, it feels like all empty space would be squeezed out.
Perhaps the behavior for points initially confined to a finite region $R$, as that
region grows larger, would hint at the situation for the infinite plane?
I'd appreciate pointers or observations—Thanks!

**Update**. Here is one of the many images from the
Lubachevsky, Graham, Stillinger work to which Henry Cohn points,
"Spontaneous Patterns in Disk Packings":

[image]
<sub>(source: [princeton.edu](https://www.princeton.edu/~fhs/lubachevsky_files/modera2k.gif))</sub>

Comment: This resembles greatly the way that "jammed" packings are prepared; see my answer to one of your previous questions http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71397/average-degree-of-contact-graph-for-balls-in-a-box/71412#71412 Of course in those models they typically simulate "soft" disks and balls with say a harmonic repulsion when two particles overlap, and they work with a finite region with periodic boundary conditions, but I expect that much of the behavior will be the same.

Comment: Interesting hypothesis, jc, that this will essentially end up in jammed-disk configurations. I thought that the gradual growth of the radii would lead to something different, but you may be right...

Comment: I imagine someone must have simulated this, but I'm not sure who or where.  I think jc's probably right about the behavior.  Incidentally, are you familiar with the Lubachevsky-Stillinger algorithm?  (For example, see http://www.princeton.edu/~fhs/lubachevsky.htm.)  It's reminiscent of your question, but the particles have momentum and bounce off each other.  It's a different model and I don't see any obvious implications for your question, but it's similar in spirit.

Comment: Probably an unimportant side question, but how does one put point uniformly at random on the infinite plain (since there is no uniform probability measure)?

Comment: @Dirk: Joseph was probably referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process#Poisson_point_process .

Comment: After some more thought I think the pictures on the page linked to by Henry Cohn should be a good representation for what happens. For packings in two dimensions, a strong tendency to crystallize has been observed if the particle radii are monodisperse, so in the 2D simulations I mentioned the particle radii are often set to be different, since the primary interest is in studying disordered packings. For 3D particles there is apparently less of a tendency to crystallize and so I expect that the result of your model will be disordered packings.

Comment: Is the process well defined when there are infinite components of touching disks?

Comment: @Brendan: I worry about that myself. It is well defined for points distributed in a finite region, and then that region could be enlarged without bound. But it is not entirely clear that such a limit of larger and larger regions is the same as the infinite plane, leading to infinite components, as you say. So: I don't know.

Comment: Here are two amazing physical simulations (using ball bearings!) of the Lubachevsky-Graham-Stillinger model, by Finnish artists Tommi Grönlund and Petteri Nisunen. http://vimeo.com/37782969 http://www.dump.com/giantsurface/

Comment: This is also an interesting question if you substitute a sphere for the Euclidean plane. I did simulations when I was an undergrad to see what the resulting polytopes would look like.